# Create a fork from a git repository, then delete some branches in the source repository. Would those branches remain in the fork?

Tags: git, github

I have a private Github repository that receives contributions from multiple groups. I'd like that some of the contributions of Group A in an experimental branch would remain hidden for a certain time from Group B. Group A has already pushed those branches on Github. So I was thinking that Group A could make a fork bringing all his branches into their fork.

Then, what happens in the future of the fork if I delete those branches made by Group A in the source repository? For example, if Group A pulls changes from the source repository, would their branches be deleted?

Is there a way I can delete those branches in the source repository while ensuring they would remain alive in the fork of Group A?

Comment: The a and b language doesn’t help here a specific name and example branch structure would help explain. but irrespective two repos are not linked together so a branch can exist in either or both repos with no direct effects

Comment: in the simplest case, there is a branch _foo_ made by group A that is already in the source repository, then they fork the repository and I delete the branch _foo_. If group A wants to fetch upstream (let's say in the master branch) from the source repository to their fork, would their branch _foo_ be deleted during that fetching?

Comment: Please edit (rewrite) the question with that example. `would their branch foo be deleted during that fetching?` git fetch is a none destructive command, not sure what you mean, something else to clarify _by editing the question_ :).

Answer (score 1):

## TL;DR

You're talking about hiding things with hidden names, having them come into existence and then go away, and asking about all of that in a weird way.  [The answer is therefore both no and yes.](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/207329-go-not-to-the-elves-for-counsel-for-they-will)  You *can* do what you want; it won't really matter.  What you need to know is how it actually *works*.

## Long

Git isn't actually very interested in *branches*.  Branches are not the point: it is *commits* that matter.  And in fact, the word *branch* doesn't really mean anything in Git—or to put it another way, it means at least two or three different things, so that nobody knows what you mean if you *just* say "branch".  We need some additional context, to figure out which of the many meanings of "branch" you actually meant.

What you meant here is clear enough though: you meant *branch names*, and by being sufficiently specific we do get some answers:

- A GitHub "fork" is a kind of `git clone` where the cloning operation happens entirely on GitHub.  It does a few extra things behind the scenes, too.
- A regular Git clone works by copying *all of the commits* and *none of the branch names*.  This matters a lot because you're concerned about branch names—but you shouldn't be so concerned about branch names!  You should *mostly* be concerned instead about the commits.

Let's start with the regular `git clone` operation, since a "GitHub fork" style clone is so closely related, but it's in the clones on one's laptop (or similar computer) that one will actually do work.

#### Understanding repositories and clones

A Git *repository* is, at its heart, two databases:

- One database—usually much larger—contains Git's *commits* and other objects (the objects needed *by* the commits, and perhaps annotated tag objects that we use to attach a little more information to releases, for instance).  This database is indexed by *object hash IDs* (or *OIDs*, which stands for Object IDs: Git changed terminology when SHA-1 began to be supplanted, but you'll still see these called "SHA hashes" or similar).  These hash IDs are incredibly bad for humans, so for the most part we just don't use them.  But Git *needs* them.  So:
- The other database, usually much smaller, contains *names:* branch names, tag names, remote-tracking names, and all sorts of names.  (Git's current implementation of this database is poor, which leads to various problems with mixed-case names on Windows for instance, but that's just a Small Matter of Programming to fix: the fix has been underway for at least 2 or 3 years and will probably be out within a few decades. )  Each name maps to *one* hash ID, and that's sufficient.

A *tag* name generally maps to one specific hash ID forever, so that a tag like `v2.23.0` in the Git repository for Git always gets you the commit that represents that release.  A *branch* name maps to one specific hash ID, but the hash ID changes from day to day as someone adds new commits to the branch: it's always the hash ID of the *last* ("latest", more or less) commit.  Each commit itself stores a list of previous hash IDs—usually just one entry long, though we won't go into all the details here—which suffices to let Git find all the *earlier* commits from that last commit.

A repository in which you *do work* has more than these two databases, but these two are the heart of any given repository.  And this tells us how cloning works: when you *clone* a repository, you copy the big database of objects (usually the whole thing, though you can trim it for very specific purposes, e.g., GitHub's CI will try to copy just *one commit* to build from since that's much faster).  You *don't* copy the *names* database though.  Instead, Git picks and chooses which names in the original repository pass through, and which get modified: normally you'll get all the *tags* copied, but for each of the other repository's *branch* names, you will get, in your clone, a *remote-tracking name*.

This is where names like `origin/develop` and `origin/feature` come from.  When you clone some repository, you run:

```
git clone -o origin -b somebranch url
```

If you don't use the `-o` option, `-o origin` is implied.  That's the *remote* name that Git will use to save the URL, and to build the *remote-tracking names*.  If you don't use the `-b` option, your Git software asks the other Git software—whatever responds at the given *url*—what branch name they recommend.  Then your Git copies their *objects* database, and picks and chooses names from their *names* database, copying the tags and turning each of their branch names—`main`, `develop`, etc.—into *remote-tracking names* `origin/main`, `origin/develop`, and so on.

You now have *all of their commits* and *no branch names*.  Then your Git creates *one* branch name of your own, in *your* repository, corresponding to one branch name in *their* repository.  You already picked that name with your `-b` option.  You now have one branch, but you have all the *commits*.  Your branch *`branchname`* identifies, as its *tip commit* (latest commit), the same commit that *their* branch, now known in your clone as `origin/branchname`, claims as its tip commit.

You are now free to create and destroy any *branch names* you like in *your* repository.  Each branch name will hold one commit hash ID; that commit will be the *latest* commit "in" or "on" that branch.  This meaning of "branch" in Git is a collection of commits, as found by starting at the tip one (stored in the name) and working backwards until some unspecified stopping point—and by default Git will work all the way back to the beginning of history, so that the very first commit ever made is on *every* branch.

Hence, the word *branch* sometimes means *branch name*, sometimes means *remote-tracking name*, sometimes means *tip commit as found by branch name*, and sometimes means *set of commits as found by tip commit and working backwards*.  This is what makes the word *branch* so useful, and simultaneously useless, in Git: [it means whatever we want it to mean](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/12608-when-i-use-a-word-humpty-dumpty-said-in-rather).  [Glory!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humpty_Dumpty#Lewis_Carroll%27s_Through_the_Looking-Glass)

#### How humans use branch names, and why that matters

We don't use raw hash IDs if we can possibly avoid it.  A *name* like `develop` actually means something to us, so that's what we use.  We add commits to the *end* of a branch, and Git makes that very easy for us to do because Git *likes* to *add commits to its big database*.  In fact, Git hardly ever *removes* commits from this database (and GitHub *never* do as we'll see in a bit).  But because we find the *last* commit with a name, and use that to have Git work *backwards*, we literally *can't* find any *later* commits if and when we ever make a branch name "move backwards".

Let's draw a simple linear chain of commits, using single uppercase letters to stand in for the real hash IDs.  The *latest* or *last* commit in this chain will have some hash `H`, and will itself contain the hash ID of the immediately-previous ("old last") commit, which we'll call `G`.  We say that `H` *points to* `G` and draw that like this:

```
        <-G <-H
```

There's an arrow sticking out of `G` pointing backwards too, because `G` is an ordinary commit: it points to (holds the hash ID of) an even-earlier commit, which also has an arrow:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

This repeats all the way back to the very first commit ever.  Since there's no *earlier* commit than the first one, it has an empty list of previous commits; this allows `git log`, for instance, to finally stop working backwards.

To say that some *branch name* like `main` *points to* `H` as the tip commit, we draw that in.  I'll get lazy (on purpose) about the arrows *between the commits;* just remember that they all point backwards:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- main
```

Now, suppose we force Git to move `main` backwards too, against Git's normal "add things to the branch" idea.  Let's make `main` point to `G`, so that the commit with hash ID `H` has to get drawn on a separate line:

```
          H
         /
...--F--G   <-- main
```

Git *needs* hash IDs to find the commits.  Where will we get the hash ID to *find* commit `H`?  Nowhere, probably: so we'll "lose" commit `H`.  It's still *there*, in the repository; it's just that without the hash ID, we can't *find* it.  If we had added a new commit in the usual way:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- main
```

we'd have Git point `main` to new commit `I`, but `I` would point backwards to `H` and we could still find `H`.

This is what `git commit --amend` does, by the way.  Git literally *can't* change any existing commit, so "amending" a commit just kicks it up out of the way, putting the new commit in so that it skips back a bit further:

```
          H
         /
...--F--G--I   <-- main
```

Since we "see" commits by running `git log main` and having Git work backwards from the latest, we never see `H` any more, and it looks like `H` *changed into* `I`.  It didn't—it literally can't—but because no human ever pays any attention to a raw hash ID, nobody notices the switch.

That leaves us with the obvious principle that **if you can't find a commit, it might as well not be there**.  We *find* commits using branch names (and tag names and remote-tracking names and all other kinds of names) and then working backwards, so once there's no *name*, nobody finds the commit.

(Git keeps extra records around for a while—things it calls *reflogs*—in "user" style repositories where you do work.  These remember hash IDs for 30 to 90 days extra by default, and then the reflog entries expire, and *then* you *really* can't find the hash IDs.  Once you *really* can't find the commit hash IDs, Git feels safe in purging those commits from the big database.  So if you accidentally commit a terabyte file, you can undo the commit, wait some months, and the disk space will eventually come back.)

#### Normal clones and branch names: the bottom line

The end result of all of this is that when you *clone* a repository, you get the commits you need, but only one *branch* name, and that branch name is *your* branch name.  *Their* branch names become your remote-tracking names.  If you want to copy their branch names—your remote-tracking names—to new branch names in your clone, you can do that whenever you want.  Those are now *your* branch names, which are independent of *their* branch names.

When you run `git fetch remote`, your Git software, working with your Git repository, will call up some other Git software at the stored URL.  Your Git (your software working with your repo) will have a conversation with their Git (their software working with their repo) and your Git will figure out what commits, if any, they have that are *new to you* and will retrieve them—or just some of them, if you limit your `git fetch`—and update all your remote-tracking names (or just one or two, if you limit your `git fetch`).  So `git fetch` means *find out new stuff they have and bring it over*.

If they *delete* a branch name in their repository, nothing at all happens to your repository.  Or, you can ask to "prune" remote-tracking names, and then your Git software will delete the corresponding remote-tracking name.  I like to turn on pruning all the time, so that I don't accumulate "stale" (dead) remote-tracking names, but that's just a matter of taste.  Note that your *branch* names are never affected by `git fetch`!  They're *your* branch names, not anyone else's—and in general, `git fetch` will only *add* commits to your repository, because Git doesn't remove commits until they become truly un-findable.

#### GitHub forks

A GitHub "fork" is basically a `git clone` with two significant differences:

- First, GitHub copy *both* databases.

  They actually cheat on the big one: they don't actually copy the commits at all, instead relying on a sharing trick that Git and libgit2 implement.  This saves them all kinds of disk space, and is quite invisible to *you*, the user.  But it makes forks cheap for them, which is good since that makes forks *available* to you.

  But because they copy all the *branch names* (plus all the tag names), your fork starts out with a bunch of branch names.  Still, this one is a real copy: your branch names, in your fork, are *yours*.  The reason they copy the branch names straight through is that they don't *make* "remote-tracking names" at all, in your fork.  There's just no such thing in a GitHub repository.

  These branch names are literally copies, so if the original repository—the one you forked—changes the hash IDs stored in some of their branch names, adds new branch names, deletes existing branch names, or whatever, *none of that affects your fork*.  Your fork's branch names are set once the fork is done, and after that, it's up to *you* to update your fork's branch names.
- Second, besides copying both databases, they set up a bunch of internal linkage, behind-the-scenes.  You can't access this linkage directly at all, but it's what allows you to create *pull requests*.  Pull requests are a GitHub invention—swiftly copied to pretty much every other hosting site of course, but the point here is, they're not part of *Git*, they're specific to Git*Hub*.  The PRs on Bitbucket are subtly different, and the things on Git*Lab* aren't even called "pull requests" (they're called "merge requests" instead).

(The "cheating" that GitHub do explains why they never expire any commit.  It's not technically impossible, it's just several orders of magnitude harder for them: enough that they don't bother, if they don't have to.  So if you ever accidentally push, to GitHub, a commit you didn't want exposed, assume it's exposed forever.  Contact GitHub support to get them to clean it out, but it *will* be "out there" long enough for some web scraper to get it.)

GitHub also add a third database—not part of Git at all—to store issues, PR numbers, comments made on PRs, and so on, and they use some special name patterns in the names database (`refs/pull/*`).  But otherwise, a GitHub fork *is* a Git clone with just a few small modifications.  Once the branch names exist in your fork, they're *yours*.

Post-forking, you must:

- `git clone` your fork to your own machine ("laptop" below);
- `git remote add`, to your laptop clone, a remote name and the URL for the repository you forked; and
- with whatever frequency you want, `git fetch` from the added remote, to pick up any new commits they made that didn't get copied to your GitHub fork during the fork-clone operation.

These new commits go into your laptop, adding to the big all-objects database and creating or updating remote-tracking names.  Let's say you use `origin` as the usual standard remote name for your GitHub fork, and `zorg` as the remote name for the repository you forked.  Then `zorg/*` on your laptop represents your latest `git fetch zorg` updates.  If there are new names you'd like to have show up in your GitHub fork, you would:

```
git push origin refs/remotes/zorg/newbr:refs/heads/newbr
```

for instance to turn your remote-tracking name `zorg/br` on your laptop into the *branch* name `newbr` in your GitHub fork.  The `git push` transfers the commits and other objects, which go into the *big* database, and then asks the GitHub-side Git implementation to create or update the *branch* name `newbr` in your GitHub fork, pointing to the tip commit as found by your laptop's `zorg/newbr`.  The `refs/remotes/` and `refs/heads/` stuff is simply spelling out the *full name* of a remote-tracking and branch name respectively—that's how the names database stores a remote-tracking name, or a branch name.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @torek for the explanations. while I had an idea of what you described,  I wasn't totally sure what happens if in the upstream I delete a "branch" (ok, let's call a branch a series of commits that are not merged into  master) if those series of commits would be deleted in the fork after doing a fetch upstream.  I want to delete those commits in the upstream while being sure the fork still preserves them.

After the long read, I did a test. I forked the repository, which has a branch *foo* with only 1 commit ahead master. Then in the upstream, while in branch *foo* I did

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
git push origin HEAD --force
```

Then in the fork, I did a fetch upstream and I could see "This branch is 1 commit ahead of <upstream>:*foo*". So then, all looking good.

In context,  in this particular repository, Group B will join the development, but Group A wants to hold for a time their contributions until publishing a study. Until now, we just have a single repository. Once Group A publishes its results, they will be ok with other groups reusing what they have developed. Group B has also a similar request, they are ok with sharing their own work once they complete their own study. So using forks for each group seems a good approach. The issue is that Group A has its branches already pushed into the single repository.  But now, I'm confident I can delete all those branches before Group B makes its own fork.